# WSO2 Identity Server authentication with response in return

Tags: authentication, wso2, custom-authentication, wso2-identity-server

I have a custom authenticator for Liferay that authenticates the user using "AuthenticationAdmin" service and service method "login()" only returns the boolean response.I

In my case I want the calling web application to know more from this login method ..like some variables that is needed by application for authenticated user e.g. some user attribute like "isEnabled", "customattr" from LDAP after authentication.

Can we return some responses from WSO2 Authenticator? How can we achieve this from WSO2 IS?

Comment: Anyone there to address this!!

Answer (score 0):

In wso2 identity server all the attributes (email,last name..etc) are stored as claims.After authenticating using "AuthenticationAdmin" you can use "WSUserStoreManager" to get claim values of user(using method getUserClaimValue).Refer "remote-usermgt" example can be found identity server sample folder or else refer this[0] blog post.

[0]http://blog.facilelogin.com/2010/05/managing-users-and-roles-with-wso2.html